# pl/sql mutation table on update

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, sql-update, mutation

I know, what this question had been conceived  many time, but I need your advice :)

Having 2 table:

- Sale_income

`| item |income |create_user |create_date        |last_update_user | update_time|
 |------|-------|------------|-------------------|-----------------|------------|
 | 1    |  100  |duck        |05-19-2016         |human            |05-19-2016  |
 | 2    |  250  |dog         |05-19-2016         |human            |05-19-2016  |
 | 3    |  210  |cat         |05-20-2016         |human            |05-19-2016  |`

- Sale_income_audit

`| item |change_id|last_inc|new_inc   |user_update|update_date|operation   |
 |------|---------|--------|----------|-----------|-----------|------------|
 | 1    |  1      |null    |05-19-2016|duck       |05-19-2016 |I           |
 | 2    |  2      |null    |05-19-2016|dog        |05-19-2016 |I           |
 | 3    |  33     |null    |05-20-2016|cat        |05-19-2016 |I           |`

The task is: when somebody doing insert, update or delete, trigger must insert a record above that takes place action into the table **Sale_income_audit** (type of operation - column 'operation). And at the same time must be update the table 
**Sale_income** (last_update_user and update_time).
I done this so: create package with 3 variables:

```
create or replace package Sale_income_var as
    v_old_income BINARY_INTEGER := null;
    v_new_income BINARY_INTEGER := null;
     v_item      BINARY_INTEGER := null;
END Sale_income_var;
```

and 2 triggers

first

```
create or replace trigger audit_income_IUD
  after insert or update or delete on Sale_income
    for each row
begin  
    .
    .                
elsif updating then  
        Sale_income_var.v_old_income  := :old.income;
        Sale_income_var.v_new_income  := :new.income;                     
             if  Sale_income_var.v_item is null then                      
        Sale_income_var.v_item := :old.item;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(Sale_income_var.v_item);
            end if;
     .
     .
end if;
end audit_income_IUD;
```

second

```
create or replace trigger  sale_income_au
  after update of income on Sale_income
 begin 
   update Sale_income set last_update_user = user, last_update_date = sysdate
       where item = Sale_income_var.v_item;     
   INSERT into Sale_income_audit   (item, 
                                  change_id, 
                                  last_income, 
                                  new_income, 
                                  user_update, 
                                  update_date, 
                                  operation)
                             VALUES (Sale_income_var.v_item,
                                     auto_incr.NEXTVAL, 
                                     Sale_income_var.v_old_income, 
                                     Sale_income_var.v_new_income,
                                     user,
                                     sysdate,
                                     'U');                         
             Sale_income_var.v_item := null;
    end sale_income_au;
```

It work, but I fell what it is wrong solution. Because updating block from 'general' trigger moved to another trigger and this magic with variables it`s not good to, I'm right?

How would you decide this task and what do you would change in my solution?
Thanks for help :)

Comment: Yes, it's wrong. Run a very simple query `UPDATE Sale_income SET income = income + 200` that add 200 to all records in a table. Then examine `Sale_income_audit` table. You will see a row only for last updated record, but the update might change even 1000 rows.

Comment: Thank you, i didn`t see this bug. but when update for table Sale_income was in trigger audit_income_IUD, then trigger were added 2 records to the table 'audit', because trigger of for each row worked 2 times, from the call of update in other trigger. @kordirko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using just one `BEFORE` trigger.
Before triggers are allowed to modify NEW values of table columns, and these modified values are stored in the table, so `last_update_user` and `update_time` columns can be updated in this way.

```
create or replace trigger audit_income_IUD
BEFORE insert or update or delete on Sale_income
    for each row
declare
      operation_type char;
begin 

  if updating or inserting then
         :new.update_time := sysdate;
         :new.last_update_user := user;
  end if;

  CASE 
       WHEN updating THEN operation_type := 'U';
       WHEN inserting THEN operation_type := 'I';
       WHEN deleting THEN operation_type := 'D';
  END CASE;

  INSERT into Sale_income_audit   (item, 
                                  change_id, 
                                  last_income, 
                                  new_income, 
                                  user_update, 
                                  update_date, 
                                  operation)
                       VALUES (:old.item,
                                  auto_incr.NEXTVAL, 
                                  :old.income, 
                                  :new.income,
                                  user,
                                  sysdate,
                                  operation_type);     
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

An answer appeared simple. Need use **after** each row  and add in block 'update'

```
    :new.last_update_user := user;
    :new.last_update_date := sysdate;
```

and we can be limited to one trigger with out package!